# Logstash / Elasticsearch - trasform fields to lowercase in output conf

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a standard ELK stack currently storing numerous log outputs. I'm trying to separate my indices to be source-specific.

As part of my FileBeats config, some standard fields are always generated as part of every message (and are location-specific), which I want to use as the basis for my my ES index:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.mydomain.com:80"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{[fields][identifier]}"
  }
}
```

However, ES is rejecting some of the indices as the field contains uppercase characters - identifier has acceptable values like *myfoo* but also could be *MyBar*:

```
[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {"reason"=>"Invalid index name [logstash-2017.06.02-MyBar], must be lowercase"}
```

The casing isn't essential and I can add a mutate filter to forcibly lowercase the fields in question, but I would prefer to store the identifier field with proper casing, yet use the lower-cased version for the index name.

Is there function which can be called in the elasticsearch output, to lower-case the field in question? Something like

```
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{[fields][identifier]}.lowercase()"
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a bit more mutate trickery.

1. Create a new field using mutate, set to your identifier.
2. In a second mutate, lowercase that new field.
3. Use the new field in your output.

Like so:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "lc_identifier" => "%{fields}%{identifier}" }
  }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "lc_identifier" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.example.com:80"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{[lc_identifier]}"
  }
}
```

You will end up with an `lc_identifier` field in your indices, but that shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Building on sysadmin1138's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/857603/logstash-elasticsearch-trasform-fields-to-lowercase-in-output-conf#857677):

You can use the [@metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata) field to prevent the `lc_identifier` field from appearing in your documents while indexed.

In your filter, change:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "lc_identifier" => "%{fields}%{identifier}" }
  }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "lc_identifier" ]
  }
}
```

To:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][lc_identifier]" => "%{fields}%{identifier}" }
  }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "[@metadata][lc_identifier]" ]
  }
}
```

And to call it in your output:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.example.com:80"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{[@metadata][lc_identifier]}"
  }
}
```

This way you can create an index pattern with a lowercase identifier, but avoid having the lowercase field appear in the documents themselves.

Answer (score -1):

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "lc_identifier" => "%{fields}" }
  }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "lc_identifier" ]
  }
}
```

---

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.example.com:80"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{lc_identifier}"
  }
}
```